# Mystery URL decoding of certain characters - Android URI / Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, url, url-encoding, urldecode

I am having a curious problem that perhaps someone has insight into.  I encode a query string into a URL on Android using the following code:

```
request = REQUEST_BASE + "?action=loadauthor&author=" + URLEncoder.encode(author, "UTF-8");
```

I then add a few other parameters to the string and create a URI like this:

```
uri = new URI(request);
```

At a certain point, I pull out the query string to make a checksum:

```
uri.getRawQuery().getBytes();
```

Then I send it on its way with:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
```

On the Appengine server, I then retrieve the string and try to match the checksum:

```
String query = req.getQueryString();
```

Normally, this works fine.  However, there are a few characters that seem to get unencoded on the way to the server.  For example,

action=loadauthor&author=Charles+Alexander+%28Ohiyesa%29+Eastman&timestamp=1343261225838&user=1479845600

shows up in the server logs (and in the GAE app) as:

action=loadauthor&author=Charles+Alexander+(Ohiyesa)+Eastman&timestamp=1343261226837&user=1479845600

This only happens to a few characters (like parentheses).  Other characters remain encoded all the way through.  Does anyone have a thought about what I might be doing wrong?  Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did find a solution for this problem.  I worked around it by unencoding certain characters on the client before sending things to the server:

```
request = request.replace("%28", "(");
request = request.replace("%29", ")");
request = request.replace("%27", "'");
```

If anyone has a better solution, I am sure that I (and others) would be interested!

Answer (score 0):

URLEncoder does not encode parentheses and certain other characters, as they are supposed to be "safe" for most servers. See [URLEncoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html). You will have to replace these yourself if necessary.

Example:

```
URI uri = new URI(request.replace("(","%28"));
```

If a lot of replacements are needed, you can try request.replaceAll(String regularExpression, String replacement). This, of course, requires knowledge of regular expressions.

Comment: The problem is that it **is** encoding parenthesis.  (which then get decoded somewhere.)  I would be quite happy if it didn't.  I am using the regular java.net.URLEncoder;  I think that is the expected behavior, however.  The [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) says: 'All characters except letters ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z') and numbers ('0'..'9') and characters '.', '-', '*', '_' are converted into their hexadecimal value prepended by '%'. For example: '#' -> %23. In addition, spaces are substituted by '+'.'